# Weights are not getting updated while training logistic regression by using iris dataset

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

**Python code:**

I have used the **`Python code`** as below. Here, machine is trained by using **`Logistic Regression algorithm`** and **`wine dataset`**. Here, problem is that weights are not getting updated. I don't understand where is the problem.

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dataset = datasets.load_wine()
x = dataset.data
y = dataset.target
y = y.reshape(178,1)

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test =   train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.15,shuffle=True)
print(x_train.shape)
class log_reg():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def sigmoid(self,x):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
    def train(self,x,y,w1,w2,alpha,iterations):
        cost_history = [0] * iterations
        Y_train = np.zeros([y.shape[0],3])
        for i in range(Y_train.shape[0]):
            for j in range(Y_train.shape[1]):
                if(y[i] == j):
                    Y_train[i,j] = 1
        for iteration in range(iterations):
            z1 = x.dot(w1)
            a1 = self.sigmoid(z1)
            z2 = a1.dot(w2)
            a2 = self.sigmoid(z2)
            sig_sum = np.sum(np.exp(a2),axis=1)
            sig_sum = sig_sum.reshape(a2.shape[0],1)
            op = np.exp(a2) / sig_sum
            loss = (Y_train * np.log(op))
            dl =  (op-Y_train)
            dz1 = ((dl*(self.sigmoid(z2))*(1-self.sigmoid(z2))).dot(w2.T))*(self.sigmoid(z1))*(1-self.sigmoid(z1))
            dz2 = (dl * (self.sigmoid(z2))*(1-self.sigmoid(z2)))
            dw1 = x.T.dot(dz1)
            dw2 = a1.T.dot(dz2)
            w1 += alpha * dw1 
            w2 += alpha * dw2 
            cost_history[iteration] = (np.sum(loss)/len(loss))
        return w1,w2,cost_history
    def predict(self,x,y,w1,w2):
        z1 = x.dot(w1)
        a1 = self.sigmoid(z1)
        z2 = a1.dot(w2)
        a2 = self.sigmoid(z2)
        sig_sum = np.sum(np.exp(a2),axis=1)
        sig_sum = sig_sum.reshape(a2.shape[0],1)
        op = np.exp(a2) / sig_sum
        y_preds = np.argmax(op,axis=1)
        acc = self.accuracy(y_preds,y)
        return y_preds,acc
    def accuracy(self,y_preds,y):
        y_preds = y_preds.reshape(len(y_preds),1)
        correct = (y_preds == y)
        accuracy = (np.sum(correct) / len(y)) * 100
        return (accuracy)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    network = log_reg()
    w1 = np.random.randn(14,4) * 0.01
    w2 = np.random.randn(4,3) * 0.01
    X_train = np.ones([x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1]+1])
    X_train[:,:-1] = x_train
    X_test = np.ones([x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[1]+1])
    X_test[:,:-1] = x_test
    new_w1,new_w2,cost = network.train(X_train,y_train,w1,w2,0.0045,10000)
    y_preds,accuracy = network.predict(X_test,y_test,new_w1,new_w2)
    print(y_preds,accuracy)
```

In the above code, **`parameters`** are mentioned as below

```
x--training set,
y--target(output),
w1--weights for first layer,
w2--weights for second layer,
```

I used **`logistic regression with 2 hidden layers`**.

I am trying to train dataset wine from **`sklearn`**.I don't know where the problem is, but weights are not updating. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please write the complete code and also properly indent it

Comment: okay, I did it.

Comment: Please provide the complete code

Comment: yes, it's done.

Comment: Try to plot your loss value with respect to iterations. If the value is decreasing, the weights are updating.

Comment: Yes, weights are updating. But, output values are same for a class of all examples in test set. Can you find why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your weights are updating , but I think you cant see them changing because you are printing them after execution. Python has a object reference method for numpy arrays so when you passed w1 , its values change values too so new_w1 and w1 become the same .
Take this example

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,2,3,4])
def change(x):
    x+=3
    return x
print(x)
change(x)
print(x)
```

if you see the output it comes out as

```
[1 2 3 4]
[4 5 6 7]
```

I recommend that you add a bias and fix your accuracy function as I get my accuracy as 1000.

My execution when i run the code [image]

the w1 and w2 values are indeed changing .
the only thing i changed was the main code and enabled the original data set , please do the same and tell if your weights are still not updating

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    network = log_reg()
    w1 = np.random.randn(13,4) * 0.01
    w2 = np.random.randn(4,3) * 0.01
    print(w1)
    print(" ")
    print(w2)
    print(" ")
    new_w1,new_w2,cost = network.train(x_train,y_train,w1,w2,0.0045,10000)
    print(w1)
    print(" ")
    print(w2)
    print(" ")
    y_preds,accuracy = network.predict(x_test,y_test,new_w1,new_w2)
    print(y_preds,accuracy)
```

Comment: i think 'dz1' values are getting zero. I printed it. Only w1 is not updating, w2 is updating. Can you explain why?

Comment: try to print op from predict, it is getting same values for a class for all samples in test set. can you fix it!!

Comment: A couple of issue in your implementation

Comment: can you please fix them?

Comment: ill point out the errors i can see in your code but if you want a more detailed answer then I recommend you ask another question

1)no biases

2)random dataset in op

3) I am not entirely sure but I have never used exponentiation for forward make sure your formula is correct

4) use relu for hidden layer and softmax for output

and i recommend that you go for functional programming and not oop programming , oop is too stiff for ML and its hard to find errors